# parsing RDD containing json data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json file with the following data:

```
{"year":"2016","category":"physics","laureates":[{"id":"928","firstname":"David J.","surname":"Thouless","motivation":"\"for theoretical discoveries of topological phase transitions and topological phases of matter\"","share":"2"},{"id":"929","firstname":"F. Duncan M.","surname":"Haldane","motivation":"\"for theoretical discoveries of topological phase transitions and topological phases of matter\"","share":"4"},{"id":"930","firstname":"J. Michael","surname":"Kosterlitz","motivation":"\"for theoretical discoveries of topological phase transitions and topological phases of matter\"","share":"4"}]}
{"year":"2016","category":"chemistry","laureates":[{"id":"931","firstname":"Jean-Pierre","surname":"Sauvage","motivation":"\"for the design and synthesis of molecular machines\"","share":"3"},{"id":"932","firstname":"Sir J. Fraser","surname":"Stoddart","motivation":"\"for the design and synthesis of molecular machines\"","share":"3"},{"id":"933","firstname":"Bernard L.","surname":"Feringa","motivation":"\"for the design and synthesis of molecular machines\"","share":"3"}]}
```

I need to return an RDD as a key value pair where I have category as the key and list of surnames of nobel laureates as the value. How could I possibly do that using transformations?

For the given data set it should be:

```
"physics"-"Thouless","haldane","Kosterlitz"
"chemistry"-"Sauvage","Stoddart","Feringa"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you constrained only to RDDs? If you can use DataFrames, then it would be very simple to load, you get a schema, explode the nested field, group and then use RDDs for the rest. Here is one way you can do it

Load the JSON into a DataFrame, you can also confirm your schema

```
>>> nobelDF = spark.read.json('/user/cloudera/nobel.json')
>>> nobelDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- laureates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- motivation: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- share: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- surname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- year: string (nullable = true)
```

Now you can explode the nested array and then convert to an RDD where you can group

```
nobelRDD = nobelDF.select('category', explode('laureates.surname')).rdd
```

Just an fyi, the exploded DataFrame looks like this

```
+---------+----------+
| category|       col|
+---------+----------+
|  physics|  Thouless|
|  physics|   Haldane|
|  physics|Kosterlitz|
|chemistry|   Sauvage|
|chemistry|  Stoddart|
|chemistry|   Feringa|
+---------+----------+
```

And now group by the category

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
nobelRDD = nobelDF.select('category', explode('laureates.surname')).groupBy('category').agg(collect_list('col').alias('sn')).rdd
nobelRDD.collect()
```

Now you get an RDD with what you need, although it is still a Row object (I added new line to show full rows)

```
>>> for n in nobelRDD.collect():
...     print n
...
Row(category=u'chemistry', sn=[u'Sauvage', u'Stoddart', u'Feringa'])
Row(category=u'physics', sn=[u'Thouless', u'Haldane', u'Kosterlitz'])
```

But that would be a simple map to get tuples (I added new line to show full rows)

```
>>> nobelRDD.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1])).collect()
[(u'chemistry', [u'Sauvage', u'Stoddart', u'Feringa']), 
 (u'physics', [u'Thouless', u'Haldane', u'Kosterlitz'])]
```